# OSX: Auto layout/constraints not displaying content

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, autolayout, ios8-today-widget

Im trying to create a view that has 2 labels in it, with auto layout enabled. Upon running of the app, it adjusts the size of the screen as it would if it had content yet nothing shows up. This is without setting any text programmatically.

This is my view:

[image: My view]

This is what happens when I run the app:

[image: Issue]

If I go ahead and add more text to the multiline label above 'Date':

[image: Issue2]

It is reacting to the text changes, but not displaying anything.

Here's my very, very short and simply ViewController code:

**TodayViewController.h:**

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface TodayViewController : NSViewController

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *multiLine;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *theDate;

@end
```

**TodayViewController.m:**

```
#import "TodayViewController.h"
#import <NotificationCenter/NotificationCenter.h>

@interface TodayViewController () <NCWidgetProviding>

@end

@implementation TodayViewController
@synthesize multiLine, theDate;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //Weather I programmatically set text or not doesn't change anything.
}

- (void)widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NCUpdateResult result))completionHandler {
    completionHandler(NCUpdateResultNoData);
}

@end
```

Comment: Is your view pinned to the bottom of the container view ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I can see the constraints are not set correctly. Thats why on the first screenshot the label is marked red.
If the constraints are properly set the color displayed is blue.
Missing contraints means, that there is not enough information for the label to show up correctly.

For your simple example it should be enough to use auto-layout.
Select your view and on the bottom-right should be a button like this:
[image]

Press ist and select "clear constrains" (Attention! This will remove all current constrains in the view).

After this you could run your programm and the label should show up at least.

Now click on the button again and select "add missing contraints"...I hope this helps.